# Why Numpy array operation can not be done with Numba?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numba

I am writing a simple code to use numpy array inside numba jit as following,

```
import numpy as  np    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import random  
import time  
import math  
import numba  
from numba import jit,prange  
nx=100  
p1=np.zeros([nx],dtype=float)  
@jit(nopython=True)  
def f(r):  
    p1[2]=10  
    return p1[2]   
u3=f(2)
```

It shows the following error:

```
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "f" failed type inference due to: No implementation of function Function(<built-in function setitem>) found for signature:
 
 setitem(readonly array(float64, 1d, C), Literal[int](2), Literal[int](10))
 
There are 16 candidate implementations:
      - Of which 14 did not match due to:
      Overload of function 'setitem': File: <numerous>: Line N/A.
        With argument(s): '(readonly array(float64, 1d, C), int64, int64)':
       No match.
      - Of which 2 did not match due to:
      Overload in function 'SetItemBuffer.generic': File: numba\core\typing\arraydecl.py: Line 176.
        With argument(s): '(readonly array(float64, 1d, C), int64, int64)':
       Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
         NumbaTypeError: Cannot modify readonly array of type: readonly array(float64, 1d, C)
```

I have seen that the arrays work inside the function well if I do not use a special index operation like y[i]=x[i]**2. But simply y=x^2 works where x is a numpy array.

Comment: You are not using *r* inside the function, but global *p1* and calling *f* with a scalar.

Comment: Thats not a issue. I have checked using r inside the function too. But same error is there.

Comment: The error says that the array is read only

Comment: @jakub what is the solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError raised when using Numba to accelerate Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401194/typeerror-raised-when-using-numba-to-accelerate-python-code)

Comment: Thats not a legitimate solution Jakub, I was already running the code without 'nopython' environment, it was doing fine, but then the error was also only showing up and the implementation of 'parallel' was not possible. However, the answer by Richard helped.

Answer (score 2):

The type of `p1` is `readonly array(float64, 1d, C)` which means you cannot modify it. This is why setting an items does not work: Numba cannot find a function so to set the value of a `readonly` array. The array is marked as readonly because it is a global variable and this is what Numba does for global variables. The usual solution in pure-Python is to use `global p1` but this does not works with Numba due to the way Numba and CPython works. The solution is to pass `p1` in parameter. In fact, it is a very bad practice to modify global variables in software engineering because of the non-locality (and such accesses are also often slower) so this is not a big problem.

Fixed code:

```py
p1=np.zeros([nx],dtype=float)  
@jit(nopython=True)  
def f(r, p1):  
    p1[2]=10  
    return p1[2]
u3=f(2, p1)
```